# A problem occurred configuring project ':audiofileplayer' - Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

It is my first time here.

Here’s the issue:
I first wanted to build My app in release mode, after I updated my app Flutter version.

Flutter doctor output:

`Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.2, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-arm64, locale en-IT) [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0) [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1) [✓] Chrome - develop for the web [✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3) [✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1) [✓] Connected device (2 available) [✓] Network resources` 
• No issues found!

but I got an error with the ext.kotlin_version that was too old (1.6.10) so I updated it

Now is : ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'

and here’s the dependencies:

```
    dependencies {         
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'         
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"         
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'         
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'     
}
```

I’ve also updated the gradle-wrapper.properties from distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
to:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-all.zip

After I run flutter build apk I got an error telling me to put my package name “com.example.namespace” inside android{ in android/app/build.gradle and I did so. And also removed it from AndroidManifest.xml

The error has disappeared, but now the situation is this, if i run “flutter build apk”

I get this:

`
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':audiofileplayer'.

> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
> Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:

```
 android {
     namespace 'com.example.namespace'
 }

 If the package attribute is specified in the source AndroidManifest.xml, it can be migrated automatically to the namespace value in the build.gradle file using the AGP Upgrade Assistant; please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.
```

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
> Please Help me, I don’t kow how to fix it, I don’t find a audio_session module, It is an external dependency I think… and If in Android studio I try to click on Tools/AGP Upgrade Assistant, nothing happens.
> `

I tried to click on AGP Assistant but it doesn't work on click.

I tried downgrading to gradle 7 and previous 1.6.10 kotlin version, but I got the previous error:
Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
`Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update      ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'`

I tried also upgradiging ext.kotlin_versio to latest version ext.kotlin_version to '1.9.20'.

I tried everything chat gpt or google suggest but nothing.

It seems that I need to set the namespace in the audiofileplayer module, but I can't find any module with his build.gradle or I don't understand how.
And audiofileplayer is updated at the last version, I 've updated all my dependencies.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the steps you've taken to resolve the problem make sense - i.e. you updated Gradle, Android Gradle Plugin, and Kotlin to the latest stable versions. It's always a good thing to do.

Unfortunuately, it looks like the problem is not on your side. It's the [`audiofileplayer`](https://pub.dev/packages/audiofileplayer) package that doesn't define `namespace` it [its `build.gradle` file](https://github.com/google/flutter.plugins/blob/master/packages/audiofileplayer/android/build.gradle).

You can create an issue in `audiofileplayer`'s repository on GitHub and then fork it and submit a pull request that adds the `namespace` field. This may not be possible, though, because that repository doesn't seem to be active. Last release was 12 months ago. You can use your own fork while waiting for the author of the package to merge your fix (which may never happen).

And of course, you can also find an alternative, actively maintained package.

Hope that helps!